# Additional payment method for subscription in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

Question about Apple's guidelines. There is a mobile app, certain functionality with restrictions, and the ability to remove restrictions by purchasing a Premium subscription through iAp. Recently, we have made a Web version of our app with almost the same functionality as the mobile one and decided to add a third-party payment system.

Here's how we implemented this in the diagram:

￼[image: Scheme]

Is it acceptable to use this payment method? Please tell if you have similar cases in your companies.

Comment: The only payment method that you can use in the app is IAP. Providing another payment method will lead to your app being rejected in review.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase

**3.1 Payments**

**3.1.1 In-App Purchase:**

> If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game
> currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a
> full version), **you must use in-app purchase**. Apps may not use their
> own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license
> keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, etc. Apps and their
> metadata may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to
> action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than
> in-app purchase.